# Meaning and translation of “Stileigentümlichkeiten”?

Tags: translation, meaning, german-to-english

This word, perhaps an adjective because of the ending, appears in the clause:

> diese Einschätzung nach Kadish lediglich bestimmten **Stileigentümlichkeiten** der 6. bis 11. Dynastie.

What does this word mean and is it possible to translate it?

Comment: Welcome to German Language SE and thank you for your question. Note that your example clause appears faulty and I presume you misquoted something. However we have sufficient context to answer your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The direct translation would be "style peculiarities," and it's a noun (in the plural), not an adjective. I'm not fully certain which english wording would be most appropriate, maybe "peculiarities of style"?

It just occurred to me why you were guessing there's an adjective:
German words with -keit or -heit are built from an adjective root and this suffix to create a noun. So "langsam" (slow) becomes "Langsamkeit" (slowness).